# how do I fix a broken blade lock?

Tags: circular-saw

the blade lock on my circular saw snapped and I can't loosen the nut enough to get the guard off to fix the broken piece. anybody know a way of loosening the nut without a blade in there or a blade lock?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. More details, including a picture of the damage, would really help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, confirm the saw is unplugged. Then hold the guard out of the way with tape. Place a box-end wrench onto the nut. Position everything so you can tap smartly on the wrench with a hammer or metal bar. The inertia/mass of the motor will delay the shaft turning and, with luck, the nut will start to loosen. Remember it is right hand thread.
You could also use a cordless impact driver. Put a 3/8" square adapter into the hex chuck, then an impact socket. Use short bursts of the gun. I have used the tapping technique many times over the years.